# labelText style overrides the red error validation color

Tags: flutter

I have wrapped a TextFormField in my own widget component:

```
class MyCustomTextInput extends StatelessWidget {
  final bool disabled;
  final String labelText;
  final String? Function(String?)? validator;

  MyCustomTextInput({required this.labelText, this.disabled = false, this.validator, Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return TextFormField(
      validator: validator,
      enabled: !disabled,
      decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: labelText),
    );
  }
}
```

In other widgets I have forms with lots of MyCustomTextInput´s. These use custom validations that i have defined in a seperate file validations.dart:

```
import 'package:my_app/shared/validators.dart' as validators;
...
MyCustomTextInput(labelText: 'I want to be orange, but standard red when validation fails', disabled: false, validators.required);
```

Now my problem is that I want to change the labelText color in the MyCustomTextInput. I can do that by defining the color with the InputDecoration´s labelStyle property, but this overrides the standard red errorValidation labelText color:

[image]

I would like to keep my files seperated, so I cannot save the color in a property in the MyCustomTextInput and change this in the different validation-definitions. And it seems that you can´t access the current validation state in the TextFormField context to change the color based on that.

So how do I change the labelText color, but respect the red error validation color when the form/MyCustomTextInput validation fails?

Answer (score 0):

If you want it to apply for the entire app, for all the text input fields, you can do something like below when you define the theme (ThemeData) for the entire app. Or probably you define the ThemeData in some other place instead of the way below without a bunch of `copyWith` method calls... Either way, use the `MaterialStateColor` states to define how `errorStyle` should be presented.

```
final theme = Theme.of(context);

MaterialApp(
  theme: theme.copyWith(
    inputDecorationTheme: theme.inputDecorationTheme.copyWith(
      errorStyle: theme.inputDecorationTheme.errorStyle?.copyWith(
        color: MaterialStateColor.resolveWith(
          (Set<MaterialState> states) {
            if (states.contains(MaterialState.error)) {
              return Colors.red;
            }
            return Colors.deepOrange;
          },
        ),
      ),
    ),
  ),
  body: ....
);
```

Comment: Thanks alot. If I understand correctly, I can use the resolveWith and the MaterialState to set the color. I tried setting it in my theme, and also in the main.ts like your example. But it does not work. I also put it directly in my MyCustomTextInput, but that did not work either. The color is orange the whole time. It´s like the ui state is not updated or the  'if (states.contains(MaterialState.error))' always returns false ☹️